# Como recorrer un array en angular

Tags: html, angularjs

Debo traer todos los registros de mi Base de datos, y como puedo recorrer el array que me devuelve la consulta y listar los registros en una tabla html

Comment: Si pudieras mostrar lo que has intentado podriamos guiarte mejor.

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza la directiva [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) que te permite iterar sobre un array y mostrarlo en la vista:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope, $http){
  
  $scope.personas = [];
  $scope.cargar = function(){
    $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .success(function(users){
        $scope.personas = users;
    })
  }
});
```

```css
table{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

<button ng-click="cargar()" >Cargar</button>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Sitio web</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="persona in personas">
        <td>
          {{persona.name}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{persona.email}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{persona.website}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    
  </table>
</div>
```

Solo necesitas especificarle cual es el modelo que contendra los datos y la directiva se encargara de cargar los datos cuando se llene el array.

Comment: Esta pregunta esta totalmente incompleta, porque la respondiste?

Comment: Listo, me sirvió mucho... Ya lo pude resolver Gracias